# Sass font-face syntax not loading font-family

Tags: css, sass, font-face

Can anyone tell me why this is not loading at all? When I inspect the element, the inspector is showing "Times Roman" Used as "Times"

This is from my main.scss file:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg';
    src: url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
  }
  section{
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg' !important;
  }
}
```

It is then converted to the following via phpstorm's sass watch:

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%; }
@font-face {
  body,
  html {
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg';
    src: url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot");
    /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.woff") format("woff"), url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.svg#svgFontName") format("svg");
    /* Legacy iOS */ } }
  body section,
  html section {
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg' !important; }
```

No errors or warnings, but I also do not see any fonts being downloaded under the network tab.

Do I need to set the chmod of fonts to something special? They are currently 755

**first edit - I changed the files to chmod 777 proxima_nova_reg.* while they look they have changed, but under the fonts tab, it still reads as Times**

[image: fonts tab]

As usual, thanks in advance

Comment: Is your path for `src: url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */` are correct ?

Comment: @TanmoySarkar phpstorm would give me a red swiggly line underneath the path if it could not find the files, so I believe it is correct

Comment: `@font-face` can’t contain rules. I’m not sure if Sass is supposed to allow you to nest it inside rules to no effect as a feature, but moving it to the top level will probably fix it.

Comment: @Ry- phpstorm's watch function creates the css file from the scss file. I will try making a separate css file to test your suggestion

Comment: @Ry- that worked. I created a "test.css" with no sass and it loaded with no problem. I wonder why phpstorm's sass watch plugin would create an usable rule like that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from @Ry- it put me on the right track. I changed my scss file to the following, which places the font-face rules before the html, body:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg';
  src: url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 100%;

  section{
    span{
      font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg';
    }
  }
}
```

As a result, phpstorm's watch sass creates the following css file, which renders the fonts correctly:

```
@font-face {
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg';
    src: url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot");
    /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.woff") format("woff"), url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.ttf") format("truetype"), url("../media/fonts/proxima_nova_reg.svg#svgFontName") format("svg");
    /* Legacy iOS */ }
  body,
  html {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 100%; }
  body section span,
  html section span {
    font-family: 'proxima_nova_reg'; }

/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

[image: screen shot of the font tab displaying the correct font-family]

Thank you all for your help